# Пагинация статей в WordPress внутри одной рубрики

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, pagination

Есть несколько рубрик. В каждой рубрике посты. Вывожу контент поста в single.php и пагинацию

```
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
    endwhile;
   echo  "<ul class='pagination'><li>".get_previous_post_link('%link', 'Предыдущая')."</li><li>".get_next_post_link('%link', 'Следующая')."</li>";
```

Но пагинация делает переход на следующую рубрику. Как сделать пагинацию только в просматриваемой рубрике?

Нужно для этого сайта [Посты](http://denis-postolenko.myjino.ru/2019/03/24/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-8-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post_link/) функция `get_previous_post_link()` третьим аргументом принимает булеву переменную `$in_same_term`, которая указывает на принадлежность поста элементу той же таксономии, вам нужно передать `true`. Т. е.

```
get_previous_post_link('%link', 'Предыдущая', true)
```